# after opening a file check if the file was modified on close

Tags: ruby, windows

I am wondering if I am doing it the correct way.

```
def checkout
  clone = system( "svn export #{file} tmp/" )
  open_file = system( "start tmp/#{@file}" )
end
```

Now, I am able to open the file I want with the default editor but how to record if the file was modified before close.

Should I create a `Process` and do `Process.wait` or something?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you are using [`start`](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) in Windows, use `/wait` or `/w` option to make it wait until the editor termination.

Use [`IO::read`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-c-read) to check file content modification. (before, after the editor execution).

```
before = IO.read('tmp/#{@file}', {mode: 'rb'})
system("start /wait tmp/#{@file}")
after = IO.read('tmp/#{@file}', {mode: 'rb'})

# Check the file content modification.
if before != after:
    # File changed!
```

If you're editing a huge file, [`IO::read`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-c-read) will consume memroy accordingly. Use [`File::mtime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html#method-c-mtime) as Arup Rakshit suggested, if there's such huge file in your repository. (cons: false positive alarm for save without modification)

Comment: if its a huge file you would be consuming too much memory for this trivial task, checking modified time seems to be the most adequate way to do this

Comment: +1 for /wait if I knew that I wouldn't have asked this question thanks

Comment: @bjhaid, I added mention about memory consumption. Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`File::mtime`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/File.html#method-c-mtime) method for the same.

> Returns the modification time for the named file as a Time object.

```
file_time_before_opening = File.mtime('your file/path')
# do file operation as you like
file_time_after_closing = File.mtime('your file/path')
# now compare file_time_before_opening and file_time_after_closing to know
# if it is modified or not.
```

Comment: sounds interesting going to check that out

Comment: User, opened the file and before_opening time was set and the user has not completed editing the file and I already get the same time for before_closing